# Why does Blazor assume a nullable component parameter is non-null?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, blazor

How am I supposed to pass in a nullable value into a Blazor component? Currently I get an error during the build that complains my value cannot be null, but the component parameter is set as `int?`.

Component Base:

```cs
public class ProjectNameInputBase : ComponentBase
{
    private string[] _existingProjectNames = new string[0];
    private bool _loaded;

    [Parameter]
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ProjectNameChanged { get; set; }

    protected bool Disabled => _loaded;
    protected string[] Errors => 
        _existingProjectNames
            .Where(name => AreNamesEqual(name, ProjectName))
            .Select(name => $"Project with name \"{name}\" already exists in the company")
            .ToArray();

    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (CompanyId.HasValue)
        {
            _existingProjectNames = await FetchProjectNamesAsync(CompanyId.Value);
            _loaded = true;
        }
    }

    protected async Task HandleProjectNameChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ProjectNameChanged.HasDelegate)
        {
            await ProjectNameChanged.InvokeAsync(e.Value as string);
        }
    }

    private static bool AreNamesEqual(string a, string b) => a.Trim().ToLower() == b.Trim().ToLower();

    private async Task<string[]> FetchProjectNamesAsync(int companyId)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        return new[] {
            "Project 1",
            "Project 2",
            "Project 3"
        };
    }
}
```

Component:

```
@inherits ProjectNameInputBase

<input type="text" value="@ProjectName" @onchange="@HandleProjectNameChanged" disabled="@Disabled" />
@foreach (var error in Errors)
{
    <small class="error">@error</small>
}
```

Consuming Component:

```
<label>
    Project Name
    <ProjectNameInput CompanyId="@Company?.Id" @bind-ProjectName="@ProjectName" />
</label>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Nullable Error]

Comment: I could not reproduce this with 3.1 or 5 or 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No repro, using .net 5.

Either you are on an older version or you are missing (mis-spelling) @ProjectName or another element. Any other errors? The error you higlight could be collateral damage.

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce on other machines. Seems to have been an issue with my instance of visual studio. The exact same code worked on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

It's IDE's fault. Just close the Visual Studio. After you opened it again. It will be fine.